Difficult 3D geometry question
This is a past problem that came up in a high school entrance examination. Question 2 asks for the area of the trapezoid PQMN. Even after reading the answer sheet, it still doesn't make sense (ex. why "CS = 3").
Can anyone explain how this problem is solved? Thank you.




$O$ is above the centre of $\square ABCD$, and $M$ is halfway, so it is positioned above the centre of the half-square with $O'C$ as a diagonal.

Thank you for your reply. Where can I get similar practice questions? Do you know of any resources (preferably online) that can help prepare for questions like this?

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3XSjAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA455&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

CQ = CB = 12.
F  = dropped perpendicular's foot from O onto CB $\Rightarrow$
CF = CB/2 = 12/2 = 6.
S = dropped perpendicular's foot from M onto CB & M = center of CO $\Rightarrow$
CS = CF/2 = CB/4 = 12/4 = 3.

Thank you for your reply. Where can I get similar practice questions? Do you know of any resources (preferably online) that can help prepare for questions like this?
